# Create project automatically in lwuit1.5

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

Can anyone tell me how to create 2 different project through coding as Projectname_MIDP and Projectname_RIM like its created in lwuit1.5 GUI Builder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When generating a project from the resource editor they are all under the base project you generated.

Comment: I think that he wants to generate this projects from code, not using the Resource editor